# Ping with IP:PORT in Python with custom payload

Tags: python, ping

I am wondering how I can ping an IP:PORT and send it a payload. I found a tutorial using `PythonPing` package but I believe there is a bug in `PythonPing`.

```
from pythonping import ping

ping('8.8.8.8:80', count=1, payload="Custom Message")
```

---

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PingClient.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pythonping import ping
  File "/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pythonping/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import network, executor, payload_provider
  File "/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pythonping/executor.py", line 159
    print(value, file=self.output)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Quickly looking at https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/ it clearly states "payload allows you to use a specific payload (bytes)" a suggest example is as follows; ping('8.8.8.8', count=1, payload=bytes(time.clock()) could you please give that a go.

Comment: May I ask why you want to send a custom payload as part of a ping request?

Comment: @MadisonCourto If the only line of code you have is `from pythonping import ping` there is an error. There is something wrong with the package. As for why I want to send a custom payload, its because I am trying to simulate a Client - Server on my localhost.

Comment: If you are attempting to simulate a client/server locally and you don't want it to be specifically be a ping request/response, I would strongly suggest looking at sockets to achieve your outcome, there are many resources on this, https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will help, I am not familiar with payloads, but maybe this will work?

```
import socket
ip = "ip"
port = 80 or whatever
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
msg = "hello"
s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

or if you want to use udp

```
import socket
ip = "ip"
port = 80 or whatever
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
msg = "hello"
s.sendto(msg, (ip, port))
```